# Couldn't Match Expected Type Against Inferred Type, Rigid Type Variable Error

Tags: haskell

What is wrong with this function ?

```
test :: Show s => s
test = "asdasd"
```

String is an instance of the `Show` class, so it seems correct.

The error is

```
src\Main.hs:224:7:
    Couldn't match expected type `s' against inferred type `[Char]'
      `s' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for `test' at src\Main.hs:223:13
    In the expression: "asdasd"
    In the definition of `test': test = "asdasd"
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`test :: Foo a => a` means "for any type which is an instance of `Foo`, `test` is a value of that type". So in any place where you can use a value of type `X` where `X` is an instance `Foo`, you can use a value of type `Foo a => a`.

Something like `test :: Num a => a; test = 42` works because 42 can be a value of type `Int` or `Integer` or `Float` or anything else that is an instance of `Num`.

However `"asdasd"` can't be an `Int` or anything else that is an instance of `Show` - it can only ever be a `String`. As a consequence it does not match the type `Show s => s`.

Comment: In GHC with the `OverloadedStrings` language extension and importing `Data.String`, you can also use the signature `test :: IsString s ⇒ s`.

Comment: Is `test :: Num => a` any different from `test :: Num`?

Comment: @mcb That depends on how you define "different". They're both errors, so in that sense they're the same. However you might argue, that they're different because they're presumably the result of different mistakes. That is `test :: Num => a` could be the result of a simple typo (forgetting the `a` before the `=>`), whereas `test :: Num` is presumably the result of the code's author thinking that `Num` is a type and not a type class.

Comment: any alternatives to such problem or it's fundamentally wrong to tackle the problem this way? here is my case where I have type class `IDP` and function `fromString :: IDP a => String -> Maybe a` meaning convert string to known `IDP`, thereafter I could pass the value downstream like `fetchValue :: IDP a => Maybe a -> IO ()`

Answer (score 8):

Yes, `String` is an instance of `Show`. But that doesn't allow using a string as an abritary `Show` value. `1` can be `Num a => a` because there's an `1 :: Integer`, an `1 :: Double`, an `1 :: Word16`, etc. If `"asdasd"` could be of type `Show a => a`, there would be `"asdasd" :: Bool`, `"asdasd" :: String`, `"asdasd" :: Int`, etc. There isn't. Therfore, `"asdasd"` can't be of type `Show a => a`. The type of a string constant doesn't get much more general than `String`.