# Why can't a type parameter be anything?

Tags: haskell

In my mind the type parameter `a` can be anything including a list. Why can't this work?

```
fun :: a -> a
fun [] = []
```

Haskell doesn't want to compile this code. I wonder why.

```
Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `[t0]'
 `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for fun :: a -> a
```

I can make it work rewriting the signature like this

```
fun :: [a] -> [a]
```

But this is not something that I am looking for as I wanted to keep the function polymorphic.
I wonder how `id` works on empty lists.

```
Prelude> :t id
id :: a -> a
Prelude> id []
[]
```

Comment: A function which only accepts the argument `[]` *cannot* be polymorphic!  A type system which allowed your example to typecheck would be unsafe and meaningless - consider `fun 3`.

Comment: I was hoping to get a 'specification' for the case when `a` is a list. It turned out I am not allowed to do it.

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you mean a *specialization*?  If so, you could either write a function that doesn't use any details of its argument (like `fun x = x`) or take an extra argument (possibly implicitly via typeclasses) which describes how to operate on arguments of that type - for instance `fun :: (a -> a) -> a -> a; fun f a = f a` - a specialization of `$`, and about the only possibility here - which you could then call on values of type `[a]`, for instance, like `fun (\x->x++x) [3,4,5]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [rigid type variable error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629883/rigid-type-variable-error)

Comment: @Fixnum, yes I did mean specialization, I am still learning and I have a lot of stupid questions, jozefg gave a nice answer below, thank you though

Comment: The `fun` function is like saying: "I will give you something that you cannot touch, smell, taste, use, inspect etc and I want you to give me something of same type back"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A type variable **can** be anything, but you (the callee) don't get to choose what.

Let's detour into some terminology. Haskell defaults to what's called "universal quantification". This means that a given type variable may be satisfied by *all* instantiations. The caller may fill it with whatever they want.

So when you say

```
fun :: forall a. a -> a
fun [] = []
```

Is like saying, "for every possible type `a`, treat it like a list", which obviously is nonsense!

It sounds like you want something more like adhoc polymorphism, which we use typeclasses for

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}
class Id a where
  myId :: a -> a
instance Id a where
  myId = id
instance Id [a] where
  myId [] = [ undefined ] -- special case
  myId xs = xs
```

Comment: So it mean that as soon as I declare a case with some pattern matching I loose polymorphism, doesn't it?

Comment: @AlekseyBykov Yes, you're asserting that the typevariable has a specific type which doesn't work. If you want adhoc polymorphism, use type classes

Comment: jozefg, so the idea is that `a` can be empty and if empty predicate holds true then `fun` has to return `a` back. I just want to make sure I understood you point about typeclasses, I need to declare a new type class that would look like `class MyType a where empty::a -> Bool`, and then make an instance for lists: `instance MyType [a] where isEmpty [] = True`, should't I? If so then `fun::MyType a => a -> a` would work, wouldn't it? But instead of matching to [] I shall use `fun a = if isEmpty a then a else fail "To be implemented"`

Comment: @AlekseyBykov yes, but make sure you make `isEmpty` a total function. I added an example of overloading a specific case of a polymorphic function

Comment: one more quick question, so I decided to go slightly different way by defining the empty value which I am going to pattern match against rather than isEmpty function that gets Bool, but now I have another problem by declaring my stuff like this: `class MyClass a where empty::a | fun:: MyClass a => a -> a | fun empty = empty` (| is a line break) I am getting `Warning: This binding for 'empty' shadows the existing binding`, so am I doing something wrong again? How can I make this warning go away?

Comment: @AlekseyBykov You can't pattern match on variables, you want `fun a | a == empty = ..`

Answer (score 0):

Let think, that it is possibe to write (it is not, but for fun):

```
fun :: a -> a
fun [] = []
```

This mean by pattern matching, that

```
fun _ = error "Nonwritten error!"
```

And this means next 2 things:

1) exists extra-data type, like:

```
data Universe = forall a. a
```

but this data don't exists in Haskell! And we have not data constructor here

2) this mean, that you signature is not right:

```
fun :: Universe -> Universe
```