# Rigid type variable in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I don't really get what is wrong with the following code.

```
data TypeA = TypeA

class MyClass a where
  myClassFunction :: a -> String

instance MyClass TypeA where
  myClassFunction TypeA = "TypeA"

bar :: (MyClass a) => String -> a
bar "TypeA" = TypeA
```

I get following error:

```
   Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘TypeA’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for bar :: MyClass a => String -> a
          at test.hs:9:8
    Relevant bindings include
      bar :: String -> a (bound at test.hs:10:1)
    In the expression: TypeA
    In an equation for ‘bar’: bar "TypeA" = TypeA
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I'm afraid that I'm missing something crucial about Haskell type system.

Comment: What was your goal with that code?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz mostly experimenting with Haskell type system and dynamic dispatch (I'm not sure it this is the case here)

Comment: It's not clear from the question that you want dynamic dispatch, no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rigid type variable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629883/rigid-type-variable-error)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(MyClass a) => String -> a
```

Means that the function can return *any* `a` type that's asked from it. Your implementation returns *one particular type* that satisfies that constraint. This is more obvious with the explicit signature:

```
bar :: forall a. (MyClass a) => String -> a
```

Read plainly, that's *for every type `a` that satisfies `MyClass`, this function will take a string and return a value of that type*.
Your version would assume `exists a` instead.

Comment: So how would one implement the signature OP defined in his question?

Comment: @Glubus I don't think that's even possible. `MyClass` provides a way to reduce a value to a `String`, but not a way to construct a new value of type `a`. The problem definition is wrong here.

Comment: Is there a way to implement something like "dynamic" dispatch in Haskell? I mean that I want to choose the function in run time. I think that it would be easiest if I define like TypeA = ValueA | ValueB. I'm just curious.

Comment: Yes that is what I thought as well at first, but the compiler will accept the signature as valid, meaning the function makes sense. We can just leave the function `bar = undefined` and the code will compile.

Comment: @Saczew, yes, if you return a (possibly wrapped) function. You have an X/Y problem, clearly.

Comment: The signature of that function is what `read` is. They just need to make `bar` a member of the `MyClass` typeclass.

Comment: Usually in OO-esque Haskell we find the polymorphism on the *argument* side.  So just be specific about what `bar` really does return: `bar :: String -> TypeA`.  Use the class for arguments: `baz :: (MyClass a) => a -> String`.  Try to make every signature as informative as possible.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Not everything is an X/Y problem just because one does not like the given contstraints of the task. This is an annoying meme.

Answer (score 6):

The function type `MyClass a => String -> a` indicates a function that can return a value of any type (with an instance of `MyClass`) of the *caller's* choosing. There is no apparent way, for example, to return a value of type `Int` (again, assuming `MyClass Int` is defined) given the value `TypeA`

Comment: The key word here, “choosing”, is why this answer deserves the top spot. It is truly strange that GHC expresses that problem is such a completely useless error message.

Answer (score 0):

`a` should be any type, and yet you return a *specific* type.
One way around it is to use the extension `existentialQuantification`. Or you extend your class as the following:

```
data TypeA = TypeA

class MyClass a where
  myClassFunction :: a -> String
  foo :: String -> a

instance MyClass TypeA where
  myClassFunction TypeA = "TypeA"
  foo "TypeA" = TypeA
  foo _ = error "unknown"

bar :: (MyClass a) => String -> a
bar = foo
```

So when you call the bar function:

```
bar "TypeA" :: TypeA
```

Comment: This answer leaves unclear, why the value `TypeA` of type `TypeA` cannot be the result of a function that says it returns an instance of `MyClass`, when the type `TypeA` clearly is an instance of `MyClass`. It would make sense for input variables, but it does not make sense for function results. As in: `bar` can never result in anything else but a value of type `TypeA`. So what more can it even mean for it to return ”any type’?