# How to parse polymorphically in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, polymorphism, typeclass

I'm trying to parse a folder of CSVs into a class of different specific types which then get compiled into a single XLSX. I have different datatypes representing the records because, while all of these are of the same category of thing, they have different fields and parsing methods:

```
data RecordTypeA = RecordTypeA { ... }
data RecordTypeB = RecordTypeB { ... }

instance MyItemClass RecordTypeA where
  ...
instance MyItemClass RecordTypeB where
  ...

-- and loads of instances for parsing, serialising, etc..
```

I run into two problems when trying to do this:

Firstly, I can't write a function which takes a `FilePath` as input and returns a list of the records appropriate to that file (I decide based on the file name). I run into the "rigid type variable" error (similarly to [Rigid type variable in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44243367/rigid-type-variable-in-haskell)). I suppose this is a type of dynamic dispatch, but I don't know how to achieve it in haskell.

```
parseRecords :: FilePath -> ExceptT ProgrammeError IO [a]
parseRecords = {- parses based on the file name -}
-- uh oh: "... a is a rigid type variable ..."
```

Secondly, were I to have that function, I'm not entirely sure how I would represent a list of these polymorphic types, as it would have to be a heterogenous list all bound by the fact that they are members of a certain set of typeclasses. I do not know in advance how many files of the different types there will be.

```
processFiles :: FilePath -> ExceptT ProgrammeError IO (Compiled a)
processFiles = ???
```

How can I achieve this sort of polymorphic parsing in Haskell?

Comment: "I do not know in advance how many files of the different types there will be" by that you mean, that there can be files whose schemas are not known in advance?

Comment: @danidiaz: no, what I mean is that there could be five "RecordTypeA" files and three "RecordTypeB" files, but I don't know that in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward thing to do is to lower this to the value level, instead of trying to do everything on the type level at compile time. Define a new type which is the sum of all the things you want to be able to parse in this context:

```
data SomeRecord = TypeA RecordTypeA | TypeB RecordTypeB ...
```

Then you can do any number of things - for example, define a list of type `[Parser SomeRecord]`, and run each parser from the list on the input. Or depending on filename, choose a different list of parsers. Then the result of  `parseRecords` can be `[SomeRecord]`. This is not the most precise type: you will have to cope with the possibility that a TypeA record is returned even if the list of parsers you supplied doesn't include the parser for TypeA, because they're all the same type.

Comment: Ok, that has worked (although I feel like I've brute-forced an abstraction in an ugly way but I can't think of any other way around it).